# HAVING句を単独で使用可能な要件は？ 集約関数かASを使用すれば単独使用可能？

Tags: mysql

HAVING句を「GROUP BY」を使用せず単独で使用可能なのはどういう要件でしょうか？

SELECT句で集約関数を使用する場合か、SELECT句でASを使用する場合であれば、HAVING句を単独で利用可能なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

標準SQLにおけるHAVING句は**グループ化を行った後**の表から抽出を行う処理です。

そのため[PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.jp/document/9.4/html/sql-select.html#SQL-HAVING)などでは（SELECT句の列リスト同様に）グループ化を行った後で一意に決まる式しか使うことができません。具体的には以下のような式です。

- GROUP BY に指定した列
- 集約関数
- その他、列に依存しない式

GROUP BYに列名を指定しなかったとしても全行をひとつとしてグループ化されるため、SELECT句で列を直接参照することはできませんし、結果は0行または1行になります。

---

一方MySQL（[Oracleも？](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8ca29f/56)）では、GROUP BYや集約関数を使っていない場合にはグループ化が行われず、HAVING句がWHERE句と同じような挙動をするようです。

GROUP BY や集約関数によってグループ化が行われた場合でも、MySQLではGROUP BYに指定しなかった列もHAVINGに書くことができますが、この場合はグループ内の**適当な**一行に対して条件式が評価されるのでまた違った挙動を示します。

```
INSERT INTO hoge(a,b) VALUES (1,1), (1,2), (1,3);

SELECT a,b FROM hoge
HAVING b > 1; -- 結果は2行

SELECT a,b FROM hoge
GROUP BY 1
HAVING b > 1; -- 結果は2行

SELECT a,b FROM hoge
GROUP BY a
HAVING b > 1; -- 結果は0 or 1行

SELECT a,b FROM hoge
HAVING b > 1 and count(*) > 0; -- 結果は0 or 1行

SELECT count(*),a,b FROM hoge
HAVING b > 1; -- 結果は0 or 1行
```

そして、ASで指定した列名のエイリアスをHAVINGで使えるのもMySQLの拡張です。

いずれにせよHAVING句に何を指定できるか、その結果がどうなるか、そしてHAVINGを使う意味があるかという問題でしかなく、「××で○○を使わないとHAVING句が使えない」ということはありません。

参考

- [MySQL :: MySQL 5.6 リファレンスマニュアル :: 13.2.9 SELECT 構文](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/select.html)
- [MySQL :: MySQL 5.6 リファレンスマニュアル :: 12.19.3 MySQL での GROUP BY の処理](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/group-by-handling.html)
- [What is the correct result for this query? - Database Administrators Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/33791)

Answer (score 1):

GROUP BY を必用としないHAVINGは「グループが無い＝表全体」の集約結果に対して条件が書ける。ということだと思います。

GROUP BYがないので 集約した結果は1行になります。それの結果をHAVINGで条件指定するので 「1行返る」または「1行も返らない」という結果が期待出来ます。

次の例は、having を使って表の行数とseq 列の最大値を比較してます。

```
select '通し番号が歯抜けです' 
from table
having count(*) <> max(seq)
```

seq が 1から始まる通し番号だとすると 行数と seq の最大値は一致するはずです。一致しない場合は「通し番号が歯抜けです」という行が1行だけ返り、一致する場合は1行も返りません。